# Why do these 2 simple pieces of code give different results?

Tags: c, x86

I suppose this is a rather rudimentary question, but I don't know why these 2 pieces of code give different results. Does the Pentium handle the variable Divider differently than the intermediate value ( 256.0 / (double)k )?

```
int j=64, k=20;  
double x, y, Divider;

Divider = 256.0 / (double)k;
x = (double)j / Divider - 5.0;
y = (double)j / ( 256.0 / (double)k ) - 5.0;
```

Results:
    x = -2.77555756156289E-16 
    y = 0.0

For reference, I am using Embarcadero's XE3 C++ Builder, which gives the same results as Builder 6. I am using the default compiler settings on both.

Comment: Some compilers guarantee that they always compile the computations of x and y to equivalent instructions. Some compilers guarantee that they do not generate the same instructions, because assigning an intermediate computation of type `double` to a `double` lvalue has an effect. Some compilers do not even know that there is a difference. Without information about your compiler it is difficult to say more, but look up `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` (introduced in C99) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you don't use SSE instructions, the compiler may well chose to do intermediate computations with the native `387` floating point unit, which does all computations with 80-bit values.

In the computation of `x`, you force the intermediate value to be truncated to 64 bits by storing it in `Divisor`. Then the next division uses an already rounded divisor; since the division is done with enough precision, the result is slightly different from 5.0.

In the computation of `y`, the division is done with 80-bit precision, so that the result is closer to 5.0 (sufficiently close that truncating to 64 bits makes it 0).

You would also get two `0` values if you use SSE (which only has 64-bit registers), or otherwise forced the compiler to do all computations with 64-bit precision.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the optimizer. In the second one

```
y = (double)j / ( 256.0 / (double)k )
```

is the same mathematically as

```
y = (double)j * (double)k / 256.0
```

This only does one division (which coincidentally divides cleanly) and is subject to less rounding error.

For `x` it is forced to do two divisions.

Comment: The parenthesis force `256.0 / (double)k` to be executed first. From other point of view since `j` and `256` are powers of two and if the compiler does ignore the parenthesis `j / 256` will be computed exactly.

Comment: True, but I have read that some Intel compilers will default to `-fp model fast=1` which can cause less precise results. The compiler wouldn't ignore the parentheses, but it may know enough to multiply `j` and `k` first. The poster doesn't say what compiler he uses, so it is just a guess.

Comment: I am using a Embarcadero's C++ Builder

Comment: No standard-compliant C99 compiler that defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` either to `0` or to `2` is allowed to change the computation of `j` to `y = (double)j * (double)k / 256.0`. Yes, the transformed version takes only one division, but this is not a legal transformation. The compiler cannot transform `r = a + b - b - a;` to `r = 0;` either although that uses fewer additions. Allowed transformations for compilers that implement C99's annex F are listed in F.8.2.